# Простая, кроссплатформенная библиотека звуков, совместимая с языком си

Tags: c, ubuntu

Рыская в инете нашел [SoLoud](https://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/), но собрать ее не получается.Есть всякие sdl, dumb и прочая фигня, но в мои задачи входит проигрывание 5 секундных звуков, не более. Также думал использовать allegro, но использовать библиотеку для игр в разработке ПО похоже на какой-то колхоз.Может быть кто-то знает максимально простую и маленькую библиотеку для работы со звуками, работающую как на винде, так и на линуксе, имеющую привязку к языку си?

Comment: есть, ffmpeg же =)

Comment: @Egorithm, тоже сложно, хочется за 5 минут присобачить,написать 1 строчку кода и не париться. 5 секундный звук не достоин ffmpegа)

Answer (score 2):

Самым гениальным решением оказалось присобачить игровую библиотеку allegro

Установка: sudo apt install liballegro5-dev

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_acodec.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!al_init()){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!al_install_audio()){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize audio!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!al_init_acodec_addon()){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize audio codecs!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!al_reserve_samples(1)){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to reserve samples!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *sample = al_load_sample("/home/user/music/sample.ogg");
    if (!sample){
        printf("Audio clip sample not loaded!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    al_play_sample(sample, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);

    al_rest(5.0);
    al_destroy_sample(sample);
    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция: gcc test.c -lallegro -lallegro_acodec -lallegro_audio -o test

К сожалению, allegro воспринимает только формат аудифайлов `.ogg`([конвертировать здесь](https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg)), но этот недостаток нивелируется простотой данной библиотеки!

P.s Если вы не хотите сразу загружать весь файл, то allegro позволяет загружать его по мере необходимости, вообще, allegro предоставляет хороший функционал в плане обработки аудио, как никак игровая библиотека. Думаю, для разработки ПО, использующего звуки как уведомления allegro подходит идеально

Comment: ogg имеет лучшее качество пи том же битрейте чем мп3. мп3 320 можно жать как огг 240 =)