# Нужна аудио библиотека совместимая с языком си

Tags: linux, c, аудио

Нужна аудио библиотека на линукс, совместимая с языком си, желательно маленькая и желательно простая(чем проще тем лучше). Задача в проигрывании коротких звуков(0.1-1 сек). Я пытался сделать проигрывание [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197984/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B8/1198304#1198304), но почему-то allegro жрет очень много ресурсов. Что можете предложить?

Ответ прошу оформить с установкой библиотеки, сборкой программы и кодом программы проигрывающей звук

Comment: libsox+libasound

Comment: Я бы взял OpenAL-soft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать кросс-платформенную мультимедийную библиотеку [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), она есть под все операционные системы (Windows, Linux, MacOS, iOS, Android). Она написана на языке C и может использовать как в C так и C++.

Я написал небольшую библиотеку-обёртку ниже, цель этой мини-библиотеки чтобы показать пример использования SDL для проигрывания аудио файлов, а также предоставить готовые удобные функции для проигрывания файла вызовом одной функции. Моя библиотека проигрывает только WAV звуковые файлы, для простоты, при необходимости можно доработать и для MP3 и других форматов, т.к. SDL их поддерживает.

В библиотеке 3 функции - PlayWavFile - проигрывает WAV файл из файла указанного по имени, PlayWavMem - проигрывает WAV файл расположенный в памяти, PlayWavError - возвращает текст ошибки (точнее полный стэк ошибки с сопутствующими поясняющими сообщениями).

Основная функция проигрывания звука это `PlayWavRW()` внутри `play_wav.c` файла, это центральная функция, её можно почитать чтобы понять как проигрывать звук в SDL. Остальные функции и макросы моей библиотеки всего лишь вспомогательные (например для сборки и вывода ошибок).

Для работы моей библиотеки нужны следующие шаги:

1. Установить SDL через `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`.
2. Скомпилировать код моего примера и библиотеки через `gcc -o play_wav_usage_example play_wav_usage_example.c play_wav.c -lSDL2`.
3. Запустить `./play_wav_usage_example`, он требует рядом наличия файла `sound.wav` для проигрывания.
4. Пример компиляции и запуска всех файлов можно [попробовать здесь онлайн](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1220717#main.c), правда сервера не проиграют звук, но программа запустится.

Пример использования **play_wav_usage_example.c**:

```
// play_wav_usage_example.c

#include "play_wav.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (PlayWavFile("sound.wav") != 0)
        printf("Error:\n%s\n", PlayWavError(1));
}
```

Заголовочный файл **play_wav.h**:

```
// play_wav.h

#ifndef _PLAY_WAV_H_
#define _PLAY_WAV_H_

#include <stdint.h>
// Play WAV from memory-file.
// Returns 0 on success, and non-0 on error.
uint32_t PlayWavMem(char const * buf, uint32_t size);
// Play WAV from file.
// Returns 0 on success, and non-0 on error.
uint32_t PlayWavFile(char const * file_name);
// Returns error stack, clears errors stack if clear_errors != 0.
char const * PlayWavError(int clear_errors);

#endif // _PLAY_WAV_H_
```

Файл реализующий функции **play_wav.c**:

```
// play_wav.c

#include "play_wav.h"

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

enum PlayWavErrors {
    ERR_PLAY_WAV_SDL_FAILED = 0xC8B30001,
    ERR_PLAY_WAV_PLAY_WAV_RW_FAILED,
};

#define MEMZERO(obj) memset(&(obj), 0, sizeof(obj))

typedef uint32_t Error; 

struct ErrInfo {
    uint32_t line;
    Error err;
    char const * serr;
    char const * func;
    char const * code;
    char const * file;
    char msg[256];
};

enum { c_max_errors_cnt = 128 };

static struct ErrInfo g_errors[c_max_errors_cnt];
static uint32_t g_errors_cnt = 0;

static void ClearErrors() {
    MEMZERO(g_errors);
    g_errors_cnt = 0;
}

#define ERRIFMSG(cond, err_, msg_) \
    if (cond) { \
        if (g_errors_cnt < c_max_errors_cnt) { \
            g_errors[g_errors_cnt].err = (err_); \
            g_errors[g_errors_cnt].line = __LINE__; \
            g_errors[g_errors_cnt].func = __FUNCTION__; \
            g_errors[g_errors_cnt].file = __FILE__; \
            g_errors[g_errors_cnt].code = #cond; \
            g_errors[g_errors_cnt].serr = #err_; \
            MEMZERO(g_errors[g_errors_cnt].msg); \
            if (msg_) strncpy(g_errors[g_errors_cnt].msg, (msg_), sizeof(g_errors[g_errors_cnt].msg) - 1); \
            ++g_errors_cnt; \
        } \
        return (err_); \
    }
#define ERRIF(cond, err) ERRIFMSG(cond, err, "")    
#define SDLERRIF(cond) ERRIFMSG(cond, ERR_PLAY_WAV_SDL_FAILED, SDL_GetError())

static Error PlayWavRW(SDL_RWops * data) {
    // load WAV file
    SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;
    Uint32 wavLength = 0;
    Uint8 * wavBuffer = 0;
    SDLERRIF(SDL_LoadWAV_RW(data, 0, &wavSpec, &wavBuffer, &wavLength) == 0);
    
    // open audio device
    SDL_AudioDeviceID dev = 0;
    SDLERRIF((dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &wavSpec, NULL, 0)) == 0);
    
    // clear existing audio in queue
    SDL_ClearQueuedAudio(dev);
    
    // play audio
    SDLERRIF(SDL_QueueAudio(dev, wavBuffer, wavLength) != 0);
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
    
    // wait while audio is playing
    while (1) {
        Uint32 queued_size = SDL_GetQueuedAudioSize(dev);
        if (queued_size == 0)
            break;
        SDL_Delay(20);
    }

    // stop playing    
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 1);
    
    // clean up
    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(dev);
    SDL_FreeWAV(wavBuffer);
     
    return 0;
}

static bool g_sdl_inited = false;

static void PlayWavInit() {
    if (!g_sdl_inited) {
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
        g_sdl_inited = true;
    }
}

static void PlayWavQuit() {
    if (g_sdl_inited) {
        SDL_Quit();
        g_sdl_inited = false;
    }
}

Error PlayWavMem(char const * buf, uint32_t size) {
    PlayWavInit();
    SDL_RWops * data = 0;
    SDLERRIF((data = SDL_RWFromConstMem(buf, size)) == 0);
    ERRIF(PlayWavRW(data) != 0, ERR_PLAY_WAV_PLAY_WAV_RW_FAILED);
    SDL_FreeRW(data);
    return 0;
}

Error PlayWavFile(char const * file_name) {
    PlayWavInit();
    SDL_RWops * data = 0;
    SDLERRIF((data = SDL_RWFromFile(file_name, "rb")) == 0);
    ERRIF(PlayWavRW(data) != 0, ERR_PLAY_WAV_PLAY_WAV_RW_FAILED);
    SDL_FreeRW(data);
    return 0;
}

char const * PlayWavError(int clear_errors) {
    static char buf[2048];
    MEMZERO(buf);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < g_errors_cnt; ++i)
        snprintf(buf + strlen(buf), sizeof(buf) - strlen(buf), "%d:%s:%d:%s():\"%s\":\"%s\"\n",
            i, g_errors[i].file, g_errors[i].line, g_errors[i].func, /*g_errors[i].serr, g_errors[i].err,*/ g_errors[i].code, g_errors[i].msg);
    if (clear_errors)
        ClearErrors();
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: что-то у вас много кода - посмотрите тут всего десяток строк

https://github.com/Ancurio/SDL_sound/blob/master/playsound/playsound_simple.c

Comment: @eri Там не десяток строк, основная функция playOneSoundFile() может и маленькая, но она использует гигансткий вспомогательный колбэк audio_callback(). У меня основная функция и то короче, посмотрите у меня на PlayWavRW() в play_wav.c файле, эта функция всё что надо для проигрывания, она простая и короткая. Остальной код это просто красивая обработка ошибок с выводом стэка и ловлей ошибок, т.е. просто доп код чтобы оформить в аккуратную либу всё. Но сам код проигрывания если выдирать то только небольшая функция PlayWavRW().

Comment: То что нужно, разбираться с sdl или прочими серьезными либами нет времени, а тут вы все оформили в свою небольшую либу и дали подробный ответ! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @bestorone Пожалуйста! Рад что помог :).

Answer (score 7):

Gstreamer не такой большой, каким кажется, но очень универсальный:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstElement *playbin;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  playbin = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin", "playbin");
  g_object_set (playbin, "uri", "file:///usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message.oga", NULL);
  gst_element_set_state (playbin, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (playbin);
  do { // ждем конца файла
   msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, 1 * GST_MSECOND, GST_MESSAGE_EOS);
   if (msg != NULL && GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg) == GST_MESSAGE_EOS) {
     break;
   }
  } while ( 1 );

  /* Free resources */
  gst_element_set_state (playbin, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (playbin);

  return 0;
}
```

Установить в среде сборки

```
apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev
```

Установить в рантайме с кодеками ogg,vorbis,opus,theora (10 мегабайт)

```
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
```

Компилить

```
gcc play.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

Выделение памяти 12 мегабайт с кодеком и со всеми библиотеками.

Comment: Благодарю за отличный ответ!

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю какая цель, но можно воспользоваться уже установленным софтом, думаю что из Си нет проблем вызвать процесс

```
ffplay <audiofile> -nodisp

-nodisp - флаг для скрытия окна думаю оно в данном случае не нужно.
```

Что касается аудио либ то я когда-то пробовал - https://juce.com/

```
JUCE is an open-source cross-platform C++ application framework used for rapidly
developing high quality desktop and mobile applications, including VST, AU (and AUv3),
RTAS and AAX audio plug-ins. JUCE can be easily integrated with existing projects or can
be used as a project generation tool via the Projucer,
which supports exporting projects for Xcode (macOS and iOS), Visual Studio, Android Studio,
Code::Blocks, CLion and Linux Makefiles as well as containing a source code editor and
live-coding engine which can be used for rapid prototyping.
```

С установкой тоже все просто

```
Getting started

Download JUCE. Unpack the JUCE folder 
and place it to some location on your computer. 
Your user home folder is a convenient place.

Go into the JUCE folder you just installed. 
Launch the Projucer, which is located there.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неплохой ответ!

Answer (score 4):

Если цена вопроса не волнует, то могу предложить Bass Audio от Un4seen.

https://www.un4seen.com/bass.html

Плюсы - крайне простой и понятный API, отлично документирована, распространяется одним dll/so файлом, имеет огромный потенциал в проигрывании любых аудио файлов, многопоточна и кроссплатформенная. (Часто используем её в крупных android/ios играх)

Минусы - Дорого. Но она того стоит.

Про документацию отдельный плюсик разработчикам, даже новички только входящие в проект менее чем за неделю свободно начинают работать с API библиотеки.